# Setting App Catalog site URL in central admin

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, central-administration

We want to set the URL for an existing app catalog site via central admin under manage app catalog.  However we do not want to disrupt any SharePoint services running. Will setting this url cause any iis reset or disruption of services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this will not reset IIS or stop /start any SharePoint service, it is just a site collection URL. Even you have existing app catalog and want to delete and create the new app catalog, it will not impact the SharePoint service. It is just a new site collection within you web app.

But it is always good, test it in lower farm to get peace of mind.

You may need to run this command if old URL still showed [Update-SPAppCatalogConfiguration](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj730454.aspx)